# Check if file exists with filesystemobject

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Do While Loop to loop through files with `.jpg` extensions so as to spot on the first one using such a code

```
fn = Dir(sPath & "*.jpg")
Do While fn <> ""
    sFile = sPath & fn
    Exit Do
    fn = Dir
Loop
```

And later in the code, I have put a line that checks if the file exists or not, so I used `FileSystemObject` like that

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Debug.Print fso.FileExists(sFile)
```

But I got `False` as a result in the immediate window, although I expect to return `True`
The file path looks like that `C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Screenshot_2022-06-08-21-25-36-252_com.unicostudio.jpg`

[image]

Comment: There is no loop as you `Exit Do` no matter what. You Have to call `Dir()` multiple times - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function. If `Dir()` finds it then you know it exists, so no need for `.FileExists`.  FSO has replaces VBA's inbuilt file functions several decades ago. You should be using them only.

Comment: If FSO says the file does not exist it does not exist. To be sure you have the right path change your debug line to: `Debug.Print fso.FileExists(sFile), sFile` this will output `True` or `False` and the value in `sFile` which should be the path to the filename.

Comment: I have used the Do While Loop because the file name is not fixed, it is dynamic

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the value of sFile variable and the path when used Copy as Path command from Widnows

Answer (score 0):

After the loop part, I have used a UDF that replaces the English numbers to Arabic

```
Public Function ReplaceEnglishNumbers(strInput As String) As String
    Dim numberArray, i As Long
    numberArray = Array("0", ChrW(&H660), "1", ChrW(&H661), "2", ChrW(&H662), "3", ChrW(&H663), "4", ChrW(&H664), "5", ChrW(&H665), "6", ChrW(&H666), "7", ChrW(&H667), "8", ChrW(&H668), "9", ChrW(&H669))
    ReplaceEnglishNumbers = strInput
    For i = 0 To 18 Step 2
        ReplaceEnglishNumbers = Replace(ReplaceEnglishNumbers, numberArray(i), numberArray(i + 1))
    Next i
End Function
```

I used the line after the loop to replace the English numbers to Arabic numbers

```
sFile = ReplaceEnglishNumbers(sFile)
Debug.Print fso.FileExists(sFile), sFile
```

At last, it returns True, so the problem was with the numbers in the filename. It seems the numbers are read differently inside the same code.